# For every normed linear space $X$, $\dim X\le \dim X^*$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading Hahn-Banach theorem section from one functional analysis book. They have given corollary which says "Let $X$ be normed linear space and $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ be linearly independent in $X$. Then there exist $\{f_1,...,f_n\}$ in $X^*$ such that $f_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}$". The proof follows nicely from one of the version of Hahn-Banach theorem. Now immediately after this corollary, they have given exercise that "For every normed linear space $X$, $\dim X\leq \dim X^*$". Now I think somehow I have to use the above corollary to prove this. I know equality holds for finite dimensional case but suppose I assume $X$ infinite dimensional, I am not getting how to apply or use the corollary (or is there some different logic to be used?). May be I am missing some silly logic. Thanks.

Comment: How is $dim(X)$ dedfined in the book. If it defines it as $+\infty$ whenever $X$ is infinite dimensional then this result would become obvious.

Comment: What is $X^\star$ for you? Do your functional need to be continuous?

Comment: If you are not imposing continuity, then you can pick a basis $(e_j)$ and a set of functionals $(f_i)$ such that $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{i,j}$. Then $(f_i)$ is linearly independent and thus $dim(X)\leq dim(X^\star)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy..they have not defined anything...

Comment: @SeverinSchraven..$X^*$ is collection of continuous linear functionals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $\dim X\ > \dim X^*$. Since $ \dim X = \infty$, we have that $n:= \dim X^* < \infty.$

Now let $\{x_1,....,x_n, x_{n+1} \}$  be linearly independent in $X. $ By the corollary there is $\{f_1,...,f_{n+1}\}$ in $X^*$ such that $f_i(x_j)=\delta_{ij}.$ This last property gives that  $\{f_1,...,f_{n+1}\}$ is linearly independent , hence $\dim X^* \ge n+1,$ a contradiction.

Comment: What would happen if the dimension of the spaces are cardinal numbers, i.e. not only  integers or $\infty$?